# Eliminate specific rows that have a string pattern in it

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a problem to find a string patter in selected rows in pandas. You can reach a smaller version of my dataset through https://bpaste.net/show/bd9ac4e6be07.

My dataset contains of 3 columns. First and second column (Wiki_ID's of content, will be referred) can be ignored for my problem.

Third column contains 4 rows for each Wiki_ID in second column. First row is the original sentence. Second, third and fourth rows specifies the features of the original sentence.

What am I trying to do is, first I am trying to find string pattern of "XXXXXXX" in first row (original sentence) of each Wiki_ID and if the search returns true for first row I want to drop all four rows of that Wiki_ID which means I want to eliminate that Wiki_ID completely from my dataset. For example if I found "XXXXXXX" pattern in line N then I want to drop lines N, N+1, N+2 and N+3. Line N will be the row which has the original sentence.

To be able perform a row by row search for my dataset I wrote below code. However during the boolean control in IF statement I encounter the error of **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'**.

I will be glad if you can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
for x in range(df_lbl.shape[0]):
    if df_lbl['Wiki_Labeled'][x].str.contains("XXXXXXX"):
       z = x + 3
       df_lbl.drop([df_lbl.index[x]: df_lbl.index[z]])
```

Comment: What does *Third column contains 4 rows* mean exactly? Can you provide example input and output please (in the question itself - not externally)? Is your question effectively if any unique ID contains some string somewhere then drop my all occurrences of the ID?

Comment: In second column (Wiki_ID) the values are repeated. First four rows are same and then second four rows are same and it goes on like that. Why they are multiplied is because in third column I have four seperate values in seperate rows corresponding to values in second column. Does it make sense now? For your last question I only want to check the first row of that specific Wiki_ID, I found the string there then drop all four rows of that ID.

Comment: You really need to provide some sample input and output... I think I know what you're asking but it'd be guess work at the moment... maybe just show the top 10 rows of your dataframe and the output you expect and that'd make it much better for someone to help out if they can.

Comment: I uploaded a small sample of my data in this link. https://bpaste.net/show/bd9ac4e6be07

Comment: For example if I found "XXXXXXX" pattern in line N, I want to drop lines N, N+1, N+2 and N+3. Line N will be the row which has the original sentence.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this with groupby.  By grouping on WikiId and keeping the first row, you  get a subframe that you can analyse to identify which rows you want to keep.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"WikiId":["1","1","2","2"], 
                   "Sentence":["xxxxxx","property discard","should remain","property remain"]})

remain = (df.groupby('WikiId').first()["Sentence"].str.find('xxxxxx') == -1) 

df[df["WikiId"].isin(remain.index[remain])]
```

This yields only rows with WikiId "2".  (discarding all WikiId "1")